# Lucene.NEt Index updates + structuremap

Tags: c#, structuremap, lucene.net

I have a simple lucene index searcher which is built by an overnight job. This is replaced with the new index (by overriding the existing index) this swap time is around a minute. (copy time)

The lucene search is inside a WCF service and it uses structuremap to bootstrap the service. 
I tried to use this approach below.
1) I have registered the index a 
                 this.ForRequestedType()
               .AddConcreteType().AsSingletons();

But, with this approach, the indexsearcher defined inside LuceneRepository as below: 
            _searcher = new IndexSearcher(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance
                            ("LuceneVendorAliasDirectory"), true);
is never released and indexwriter (in the indexing job) fails to swap the index.

2) I had to use the approach below of creating instance per WCF call
           this.ForRequestedType()
               .AddConcreteType()
              .LifecycleIs(new StructureMapOperationContextLifecycle());

What this means is for each WCF call, it creates new instance of lucene repository, with 500k of data its not a good solution if 50 clients call the service at the same time.

-I would like to get some help for my number 1 approach. 
What is the best practise of having single instane of lucene repository and getting it updated?

We donot have any maintenance window so the service cannot be down.

Answer (score 1):

IndexSearcher(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance
("LuceneVendorAliasDirectory"), true);Sounds like a pretty shaky solution to me.  If you want to avoid downtime, you should be copying the index to a new location and pointing to it after its done.  Otherwise, it might be read when it's in an inconsistent state.

I think you need to make your wcf app aware of when the index is done being swapped out, then you can do something like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(c => c.ForRequestedType<IndexSearcher>()
  .Singleton().TheDefault.Is
  .Object(new IndexSearcher(
    ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance("LuceneVendorAliasDirectory"), true)));
```

This will replace the current instance with a new one, but reuse it as a singleton in future requests.

PS - looks like you are on an old version of StructureMap, so my syntax might be a bit off.

Comment: I couldn't find an easy way to wrap alias directory in a repository and came up with solution. Do you have better suggestions for IndexSearcher(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance ("LuceneVendorAliasDirectory"),true. Also, while executing configure, there might be some other thread accepting request I think we will need to put some lock around it. I will give it a try.